# Google speech to text different results with API and Website

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have been using the Google speech-to-text API to transcribe audio. Recently, I tried some of my audio files on the [Google ASR website](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text) and obtained different results.

Any ideas why this would be the case? Does Google perform some pre-processing under the hood when using the website?`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it uses any processing on website, 
I have tried transcribing the same audio stream with the same code and I get the same transcripts.
But if I check the interim results of streaming function then it takes into account a different audio chunk each time and sometimes produce different results.
It just the underministic nature of the system that makes this happen.